# JQuery Show Hide & Traversing

Tags: jquery

*I am confusing my self with traversing.*

I am trying show a edit link and some text.  With the option to add/edit the text (textarea).

1) If the text is empty the text "panel" will be hidden and clicking the corresponding edit link will show an empty text area field.
2) If there is text, panel will be shown containing the text.  Clicking this corresponding edit link will also show a text area field (populated).

```
$(function () {
$('.myLink').show();
$(".showText").each(function () {
    if (!$.trim($(this).html()) == '') {
        $('.panel').hide();
        $('.showText').hide();
        $('.editText').hide();
    } else {
        $('.panel').show();
        $('.showText').show();
        $('.editText').hide();
    }
});
$('.myLink').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').next().slideToggle("fast");
    // $('.panel').closest().show();
    // $('.showText').closest().hide();
    // $('.editText').closest().show();
});});
```

---

```
<table border="1">
<tr class="topinfo">
    <td>
        <p class="myLink">EDIT</p>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="panel">
    <td>
        <div class="showText">
            Hello World
        </div>
        <div class="editText">
            <textarea>Hello World</textarea>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="topinfo">
    <td>
        <p class="myLink">EDIT</p>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="panel">
    <td>
        <div class="showText">
        </div>
        <div class="editText">
            <textarea></textarea>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I am not traversing correctly.

http://jsfiddle.net/nope_four/hgp0hdxe/

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like

```js
$(function() {
  $('.myLink').show();
  $('.editText').hide();
  $(".showText").filter(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).html()) == ''
  }).closest('.panel').addClass('empty');
  $('.myLink').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
      $panel = $(this).closest('tr').next().toggleClass('edit'),
      isEdit = $panel.hasClass('edit');
    if ($panel.hasClass('empty')) {
      if (isEdit) {
        $panel.slideDown();
      } else {
        $panel.slideUp();
      }
    }
    $panel.find('.showText').toggle(!isEdit);
    $panel.find('.editText').toggle(isEdit);
  });
});
```

```css
.editText {
  display: none;
}
.panel.empty {
  display: none;
}
.panel.empty .showText {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr class="topinfo">
    <td>
      <p class="myLink">Link</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="panel">
    <td>
      <div class="showText">Hello World</div>
      <div class="editText">
        <textarea>Hello World</textarea>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="topinfo">
    <td>
      <p class="myLink">Link</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="panel">
    <td>
      <div class="showText"></div>
      <div class="editText">
        <textarea></textarea>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The main problem was your selectors, you are targeting all `.panel` elements instead of targeting only the panel related to current link.

Answer (score 0):

**Working Example**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbQyvb

HTML

```
<div class="title">Link
  <div class="content">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
      elit. Sed at tincidunt urna. Quisque vitae ipsum
      sed purus suscipit lobortis eget luctus nulla. 
      Aenean vel euismod tortor. In nec eleifend diam
      et pellentesque lorem. Aliquam condimentum a enim
      et suscipit. Suspendisse sit amet elit 
      condimentum, consectetur dolor non, mollis nibh
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="title">Link
  <div class="content">
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  margin: 1em;
}

.content {
  font-size: 0.5em;
  font-weight: normal;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

textarea {
  margin: 1em !important;
}
```

Script

```
var content = $(".content");
var title = $(".title");

content.hide();

title.click(function() {
  $(this).children(".content").toggle();
  if( $(this).find('div.content p').is(":empty") ) {
    $(this).find('p').replaceWith('<textarea></textarea>');
    $(this).find('textarea').click(function(event){
      event.stopPropagation()
    });
  }
});
```